# Width of the two table is not synchronized while zooming the browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here i place two table elements inside the div .The browser window zooming level is 100% there is no issue in the table width .If we increase or decrease the zooming level from 100% table width is changed like the below image.

[FiddelLink](http://jsfiddle.net/s3jas62d/3/)

[image: zoom level is 100%]

[image: Zoom Level is increased]

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="parent" style="height: 44px; background: green;">
    <table cellspacing="0" style="height: 100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="first">
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table cellspacing="0" style="height: 100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="second">
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body
    {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
    .timeUnit {
        border-spacing: 0px;
        zoom: 1;
        padding: 0;
        white-space: nowrap !important;
        border-left: 1px solid orange;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: lightgray;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
```

**Script code**

```
      $(document).ready(function () {

        var totalWidth = 1000;
        var $fitst = $("#first");

        var x = 200;
        while (x <= totalWidth) {

            var $timeUnitDiv = $('<td  class="timeUnit" style="height:100%;position : static; text-align: center;" ></td>');
            $fitst.append($timeUnitDiv);
            var $div = $('<div style="width: ' + (200 - 1) + 'px' + ';" ></div>').appendTo($timeUnitDiv);
            x += 200;
        }

        x = 25;
        $fitst = $("#second");
        while (x <= totalWidth) {

            var $timeUnitDiv = $('<td  class="timeUnit" style="height:100%;position : static; text-align: center;" ></td>');
            $fitst.append($timeUnitDiv);
            var $div = $('<div style="width: ' + (25 - 1) + 'px' + ';" ></div>').appendTo($timeUnitDiv);
            x += 25;
        }

        var $parent = $("#parent");
        $parent.width(totalWidth);


    });
```

This issue will happen in all browser.please anyone help me to resolve this issue

Comment: My first suggestion would be to simplfy your HTML/CSS. You have plenty of unnecessary styles, that don't do anything (like `position: static` and `height: 100%` on the table cells). And do you really need the divs inside the cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the problem by assigning a width to your two tables.

Add the following CSS rule:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Also, you need to make sure that the parent container's width can accomodate
the the table cell contents, which consists of `div`'s with specified widths.

In this case, the table cell's have a total width of 200px.

If you change the inline style as follows:

```
<div style="height:44px;background:green;width:200px">
```

set the width to `200px` instead of `191px` and that seems to fix the
problem if you are zooming out.

If you use `width: auto` (default) on the `table`'s, the computed widths are slightly
different which is what you see when you zoom out.  The behavior is browser dependent
since the CSS specification does not say anything about how content should zoom in/out.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/gd8hL1d9/

**Note:** I found that if you zoom in, the width problem appears again for a parent `div`
width of 200px.  However, if I use 220px the zoom works both going in and going out.
I am not sure exactly why this is the case, but it probably is related to how tables
determines widths and so on.

**Alternate Solution Using Div's**

I would start with the following mark-up:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="timeUnit">
        <div class="tickUnit t1"></div>
        <div class="tickUnit t2"></div>
        <div class="tickUnit t3"></div>
        <div class="tickUnit t4"></div>
        <div class="tickUnit t5"></div>
        <div class="tickUnit t6"></div>
        <div class="tickUnit t7"></div>
        <div class="tickUnit t8"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can repeat the `.timeUnit` as often as needed.

For the CSS:

```css
.parent {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: auto; /* to enclose the floats */
    width: 1000px; /* set to n x 200 where n is the number of time units */
}
.timeUnit {
    border-left: 1px solid orange;
    background: lightgray;
    width: 199px;
    height: inherit;
    float: left;
}
.tickUnit {
    border-left: 1px solid orange;
    width: 24px;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
}
.tickUnit.t1 {
    border-left: none;
}
```

Start with a block level element `.timeUnit`, with a left border and a width of 199px 
and float to the left.

Within `.timeUnit`, place 8 child div's, `.tickUnit` with width of 24px plus 1px left
border.  Set height to 50% and then use relative positioning to shift down to bottom
edge.

Finally, remove the left border on the first tick unit.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/5j75Ltek/

**More Bulletproof Version Using CSS Table Cells**

Floats tend to show quirks when zooming to the extremes.

I would build the HTML as follows:

```
<div class="parent"><div class="timeUnit">
        <div class="tickUnit t1"></div>
        <div class="tickUnit t2"></div>
        <div class="tickUnit t3"></div>
        <div class="tickUnit t4"></div>
        <div class="tickUnit t5"></div>
        <div class="tickUnit t6"></div>
        <div class="tickUnit t7"></div>
        <div class="tickUnit t8"></div>
    </div><div class="timeUnit">
        <div class="tickUnit t1"></div>
        <div class="tickUnit t2"></div>
        <div class="tickUnit t3"></div>
        <div class="tickUnit t4"></div>
        <div class="tickUnit t5"></div>
        <div class="tickUnit t6"></div>
        <div class="tickUnit t7"></div>
        <div class="tickUnit t8"></div>
    </div></div>
```

Note that I am leaving NO whitespace between div's, this is important.

For the CSS:

```css
.parent {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: hidden; /* fixes large zoom quirk */
    width: 1000px
    white-space: nowrap; /*prevents wrapping around at large zooms */
}
.timeUnit {
    border-left: 1px solid orange;
    background: lightgray;
    width: 199px;
    height: inherit;
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.tickUnit {
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.tickUnit:before {
    content:'\a0';
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 1px solid orange;
}
.tickUnit.t1:before {
    border-left: none;
}
```

Use CSS tables with `display: inline-table` with a left border on the `.timeUnit` block
and then `display: table-cell` on the child `.tickUnit` with width 12.5%.

Finally, use a pseudo element to place the half-height minor tick marks.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/skagwx61/

The CSS table-cell seems to work best for zooming in/out.

Comment: i try this but issue is not fixed

Comment: @Sindhu I found a fix, please take a look.

Comment: @MarcAudet I'm Checking with 110% it is not fixed

Comment: @Sam1604 What browser? I checked the Fiddle in Firefox and it seems to work... I will test some more.

Comment: @MarcAudet I'm using Google Chrome

Comment: i also check that now it works. but zoom level is set 25% again the issue is occur

Comment: Please check again, I updated the fiddle, make sure you are testing with the 220px width on the parent block. @Sindhu

Comment: @Marc Audet again i get the same issue will you please check this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/s3jas62d/3/

Comment: @Sindhu I see the problem, the widths are out of sync.  I took a look at the fiddle, is the JavaScript essential or can I just copy/clone the HTML by hand? It looks like you are building some type of a widget with a scale/ruler, so the JS would allow you to expand it responsively.

Comment: So your goal is to create a repeating unit with a major tick mark on the left followed by 7 minor tick marks evenly spaced.  If I were doing this I would create a single table with two rows, with the two rows having the same number of cells and adjust the border colors accordingly to get the visual effect.  After that, use JQuery to clone the repeating unit.

Comment: @Marc Audet ,i check the edited fiddle but we cant able to use this code.atleast we need a two div's one for timeunit and one for tick units

Answer (score 2):

Here i'm set `td` width of first table is 200px and second table td's width as 25px (8 x 25 = 200)

From that i can resolve as follow

```
<div style="height:44px;background:green;width:220px">
    <table cellspacing="0" style="height: 100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="timeUnit" style="height: 100%; position: static; text-align: center; width:200px;">
                    <div style="width: 100%;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table cellspacing="0" style="height: 100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="timeUnit" style="height: 100%; position: static; text-align: center; width:25px;">
                    <div style="width: 100%;"></div>
                </td>
                <td class="timeUnit" style="height: 100%; position: static; text-align: center; width:25px;">
           <div style="width: 100%;"></div>
                </td>
                <td class="timeUnit" style="height: 100%; position: static; text-align: center; width:25px;">
                  <div style="width: 100%;"></div>
                </td>
                <td class="timeUnit" style="height: 100%; position: static; text-align: center; width:25px;">
                    <div style="width: 24px;"></div>
                </td>
                <td class="timeUnit" style="height: 100%; position: static; text-align: center; width:25px;">
                    <div style="width: 24px;"></div>
                </td>
                <td class="timeUnit" style="height: 100%; position: static; text-align: center; width:25px;">
                    <div style="width: 100%;"></div>
                </td>
                <td class="timeUnit" style="height: 100%; position: static; text-align: center; width:25px;">
                   <div style="width: 100%;"></div>
                </td>
                <td class="timeUnit" style="height: 100%; position: static; text-align: center; width:25px;">
                   <div style="width: 100%;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

### **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/gd8hL1d9/5/)**

[Check at Full Screen Mode](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/gd8hL1d9/5/show/)

Comment: This is probably a cleaner way of doing it.  Since specifying the width of `td` fixes the problem, this suggests that the root cause is related to how tables compute table cell widths.  However, the key is to make sure that the parent block has enough width for the resulting table.

Comment: @MarcAudet Thanks for reviewing my answer. I'm happy with your comments.